# Magento 2 : Missing Account Links in Mobile Menu

Tags: magento2, menu, navigation, mobile-menu

[image: My theme is built on blank theme]

I don't know, why all my account links are missing in mobile menu. Can anyone help me on this?
Here are overrided default.xml

```
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
<body htmlClass="page">
    <block name="require.js" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::page/js/require_js.phtml" />
    <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config"/>
        <block class="Magento\Translation\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="translate-config"/>
        <block class="Magento\Translation\Block\Js" name="translate" template="Magento_Translation::translate.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml"/>
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Notices" name="global_notices" template="html/notices.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" /> 
        <referenceBlock name="compare-products-link" remove="true" /> 
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="main.content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content.target" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/skiptarget.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="target_id" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container" >
        <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
            <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                        <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <!-- <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/> -->
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </container>
        <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content site-header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                    <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
                <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">選單</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
                    <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                    <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
                </arguments>
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Settings</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="switch/languages.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
```

My extended default.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
            <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                 <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" /> 
                <referenceBlock name="compare-products-link" remove="true" /> 
                <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/> 
                </block>
            </referenceContainer>
            <!--         <move element="register-link" destination="header.links"/> -->
            <!--         <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/> -->
            <!--         <move element="authorization-link" destination="top.links" after="-"/>   --> 
   <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />           <!--for Create Account Link-->
        <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
   </referenceBlock>
    <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>
    <move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>        
    <!--        <referenceBlock name="top.links" remove="true"/> -->
    <referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="header.panel" remove="true"/>

</body>
```

Comment: The submenu for the user account is presented with the "header.links". You moved this element to the "header-wrapper" element. Do you see the user account submenu in the mobile, when you comment out the line 
`<move element="header.links" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo"/>` in your default.xml file?

Answer (score 10):

This happened to me when I made a custom theme.

I created a `theme.js` file in `app/design/fontend/<CUSTOM_THEME>/default/web/js/` to use some library I added.

But I forgot to copy the code that where already there in the `theme.js` of the blank theme (`/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/js/theme.js`).

Here is the JavaScript line which clones the links to the mobile menu :

```
    $('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');
```

Check if you have your own `theme.js` that could overwrite the default one.

If it doesn't work, check the mobile menu with the luma theme, and blank theme to be sure it works with default themes.

**Edit for Magento 2.2+ :**

Since Magento 2.2.0 ([see commit](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/f793c253c90a87ac8439f38f35431982d7c41319)), the `theme.js` file has been moved to `/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js`.

Comment: This works for me when user is not logged in. However this breaks again after log in. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you move some header elements in your theme ? If you translated the welcome message when logged in, it may also break your JS if there is a quote. What happens exactly when it "breaks" ?

Comment: It started working now. Seems like magic ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @Cladiuss

Comment: Actually, the file is located in /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js just in case if anybody is wondering where the file is

Comment: @zlep Thank you for pointing this out ! I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, I had a similar issue but it was because I'd moved the **.header.links** ul out of the **.panel.header** div. So, the code referenced in the theme.js file that @Cladiuss references above `$('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');` wasn't firing. I copied the theme.js file to my custom theme, then changed the `$('.panel.header > .header.links')` to `$('.[newparentdiv] > .header.links')` and the account links started showing up again.