# Magento 2 : Missing Account Links in mobile view

Tags: magento2.3, menu, navigation, mobile-menu

I am not getting how the contents of my account links are not displaying when viewed as mobile format. You can see in the image there is no links under account tab.
[image]

Here is my overridden default.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">

        <container name="header.panel.wrapper.mobile" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="header.panel.wrapper">

            <container name="header.panel.wrapper.mobile.container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div">

                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="headline-item">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header-headline</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links.desktop" after="headline-item">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links desktop</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer.desktop" template="Magento_Customer::account/customer.phtml" before="-">
                        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links.desktop">
                            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link.desktop">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Link" name="wish-list-link.desktop" after="my-account-link">
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</argument>
                                </arguments>
                            </block>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login.desktop" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link.desktop" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/register.phtml">>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sign Up</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </container>

        </container>

        <container name="header.panel.wrapper.menu" htmlClass="wrapper-header-menu" htmlTag="div" after="-">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper.menu.container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mobile" template="Magento_Theme::header/links/menu.phtml" />
            </container>
        </container>


    </referenceContainer>


    <referenceBlock remove="true" name="skip_to_content" />

    <move element="top.search" destination="header.panel.wrapper.menu.container" after="-" />


    <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">store-menu</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="side__navigation">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">side__navigation</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="store.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">store-links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="store.settings">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">store-settings</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>



    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="page.before.footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-exclude-tax" after="page.content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-exclude-tax</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>



    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">

        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-shopping_guide">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-shopping-guide</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-shoplist">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-shoplist</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-sns">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-sns-icons</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>

</body>
```

I also followed this link as well: [Magento 2 : Missing Account Links in Mobile Menu](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/163498/magento-2-missing-account-links-in-mobile-menu)

but not working in my case. Does anyone has faced same type of errors and later solved? Please help if you had solved this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check if "header.links.desktop" is removed from XML

Comment: No, header.links.desktop has not been removed, I had not added the line to remove header.links.desktop. It is strange how the account links are not displaying...

Comment: Have you tried Luma's default.xml file in place of your default.xml file to check if the issue is with this file or any other module confliction?

Comment: Yeah, already tried that one as well. But if I changed to default theme as Luma not my custom theme as that case it is showing the account menu, might that be the problem with js or any conflict with css..

Comment: Yes, so this might be an issue of any customization in your theme.

Comment: Had similar issue was all down the to a issue with the less compilation it had hidden all links was very frustrating to find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by changing my default.xml template like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="3columns"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="header.container">
        <container name="header.panel.wrapper.mobile" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="header.panel.wrapper">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper.mobile.container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="global-guide-popup">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">global-guide-popup</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="headline-item">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header-headline</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </container>
        <container name="header.panel.wrapper.menu" htmlClass="wrapper-header-menu" htmlTag="div" after="-">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper.menu.container" htmlClass="container" htmlTag="div">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.mobile" template="Magento_Theme::header/links/menu.phtml" />
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock remove="true" name="skip_to_content" />
    <move element="currency" destination="header.panel.wrapper.mobile.container" after="header.links" />
    <move element="top.search" destination="header.panel.wrapper.menu.container" after="-" />
    <referenceBlock remove="true" name="header.links" />

    <referenceBlock name="store.menu">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">store-menu</argument>
        </arguments>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="side__brand__navigation">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">brand__navigations</argument>
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">nav brands links</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="side__navigation">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">side__navigation</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceBlock name="store.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">store-links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>

    <referenceBlock name="store.settings">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">store-settings</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="page.before.footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-exclude-tax" after="page.content">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-exclude-tax</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>

    <referenceBlock name="footer_links" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-shopping_guide">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-shopping-guide</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-shoplist">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-shoplist</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-sns">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer-sns-icons</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="form.subscribe" remove="true"/>
    <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links.desktop" before="minicart">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links desktop</argument>
            </arguments>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="global-flag" after="register-link.desktop">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">global-flag</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>

            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer.desktop" template="Magento_Customer::account/customer.phtml" after="back-to-home">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Navigation" name="top.links.desktop">
                    <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link.desktop">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Wishlist\Block\Link" name="wish-list-link.desktop" after="my-account-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navagation-logout-link">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customer/account/logout</argument>
                            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">ログアウト</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login.desktop" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

No need to edit js files. But it took lot of trouble to find out this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Paste this code in `theme.js`  file  and put that file inside `Magento_Theme/web/js`

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    $('.header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you moved `.header.links` from `.panel.header` **container** to another **container**, and the javascript that clones the links does not find the element to be cloned, and the javascript that clones the links looks like this:

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/smart-keyboard-handler',
    'mage/mage',
    'mage/ie-class-fixer',
    'domReady!'
], function ($, keyboardHandler) {
    'use strict';

    if ($('body').hasClass('checkout-cart-index')) {
        if ($('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates').length > 0 &&
            $('#co-shipping-method-form .fieldset.rates :checked').length === 0
        ) {
            $('#block-shipping').on('collapsiblecreate', function () {
                $('#block-shipping').collapsible('forceActivate');
            });
        }
    }

    $('.cart-summary').mage('sticky', {
        container: '#maincontent'
    });

    $('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');

    keyboardHandler.apply();
});
```

You need to copy the `theme.js` file from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/frontend/web/js/theme.js` to your current theme `app/design/VendorTheme/vendor-theme/Magento_Theme/web/js/theme.js` and modify this line:

```
$('.panel.header > .header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');
```

in that:

```
$('.header.links').clone().appendTo('#store\\.links');
```

> The javascript code from `theme.js` is from **Magento 2.3.7**, but for other versions of **Magento2** it is the same file, only the content of the file differs slightly.